# spl_autoload_reqister classes not getting loaded

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I have a folder structure that looks like

```
base_dir-
        Includes.php
        Libs-
             Database.php
             Log.php
             Cofing.php
        Models-
             someClass.php
        Scheduled-
             test.php
```

My `Includes.php` has

```
spl_autoload_register(NULL, FALSE);

spl_autoload_extensions('.php, .class.php, lib.php');

function libLoader($name) {
    $file = 'Libs/' . $name . '.php';
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        // throw new Exception("Error Loading Library: $file does not exists!", 1);
        return FALSE;
    }
    require_once $file;
}

function modelLoader($name) {
    $file = 'Models/' . $name . '.php';
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        // throw new Exception("Error Loading Library: $file does not exists!", 1);
        return FALSE;
    }
    require_once $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('libLoader');
spl_autoload_register('modelLoader');
```

My `someClass.php` has

```
require_once '../Includes.php';
class someClass extends Database
{
    public function __construct() { return 'hello world'; }
}
```

And `test.php` has

```
require_once '../Includes.php';

try {
     $loads = new someClass();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I run `test.php` I get someClass not found on .../Scheduled/test.php

Does spl works with extended classes like someClass.php or do I need to include the class to be exended?

And why it wouldnt find `someClass.php`?

Thanks

Comment: This might sound stupid, but if you're using an autoloader, why do you have `require_once '../Includes.php';` in your `someClass.php`?

Comment: Try changing `$file = 'Models/' . $name . '.php';` to `$file = __DIR__ . '/Models/' . $name . '.php';` in your models autoloader, and the equivalent in your libLoader too ensure that it's searching from the correct directory, and not the directory where your test.php file is located

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks that actually solved the problem. Can you make it an answer so I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$file = 'Models/' . $name . '.php';
```

to

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/Models/' . $name . '.php';
```

in your models autoloader (and the equivalent in your libLoader) to ensure that it's searching from the correct directory, and not the directory where your test.php file is located